# scale_fill_manual is only applying to the legend and not bars

Tags: ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

I have a data frame (df) that looks like the following:

| gene | p_value | p_value_dif | p-value category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0.06 | 0.01 | non-sig |
| c | 0.07 | 0.02 | non-sig |
| d | 0.008 | - 0.03 | sig |
| e | 0.009 | - 0.04 | sig |

I have created a diverging bar graph with the following code:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=gene, 
                y=p_value_dif , 
                label=p_value_dif )) + 
 geom_bar(stat='identity', 
          aes(fill= (as.factor(p_value_dif)), 
          width=0.9)  +
  scale_fill_manual("legend", 
                    values = c("Significant" = "black", "Insignificant" = "orange"))+
  coord_flip()
```

The issue is that only my legend changes colors to black and orange. The bars remain grey. What can I do so that the colors in my legend match the colors of my bars?

Note: if "fill" is not set to "as.factor" I get the following:
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your column `p_value_dif` does not contain any values `"Significant"` or `"Insignificant"`. Only these values will be filled "black" or "orange". All other values will be filled with the default `na.value` of the scale. Instead you could map your column `p-value.category` on fill and set your fill colors and labels like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=gene, 
               y=p_value_dif , 
               label=p_value_dif )) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', 
           aes(fill= `p-value.category`), 
               width=0.9)  +
             scale_fill_manual("legend", 
                               values = c("sig" = "black", "non-sig" = "orange"),
                               labels = c("sig" = "Significant", "non-sig" = "Insignificant"))+
             coord_flip()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
         check.names = FALSE,
                gene = c("a", "c", "d", "e"),
             p_value = c(0.06, 0.07, 0.008, 0.009),
         p_value_dif = c("0.01", "0.02", "- 0.03", "- 0.04"),
  `p-value.category` = c("non-sig", "non-sig", "sig", "sig")
)
```